# Shorten code for serial port WPF .NET Core with MVVM Toolkit, multi thread issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-core, mvvm

in my first code for wpf (.NET core), i have class:
`public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable`
i start shorten this code (worked fine) in my MainViewModel:

```
public class SerialCommViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
//#region private field
/* field ICommand and other bool field for other function */
SerialPort serial; 
/* region: ICommand properties and public Properties, boring coding as always */
//constructor: serial = new SerialPort;
private void StartListening()
{
      //set up com port baudrate, stopbits and open...
        serial.Open();
        serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);      
    //OnPropertyChanged("WindowTitle");
}
private void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //check serial port open and get data           
if (sender is SerialPort port)
{
            byte[] data = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
            port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            string s = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data);

            port.Write("ok");

            //OutputText is binded into Textbox
            OutputText += s + SelectedLineEnding;
            OnPropertyChanged("OutputText");
        } 
}
```

It works just fine. The code with whole project took too many lines so im using MVVM toolkit community to rewrite it.

New project rewriting currently have a button binding command `TextChangeCommand` and a TextBox binding `DataReceived` (which generated by MVVM toolkit)
Code of MainViewModel:

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    SerialPort serial;

    /*some field for other function*/

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(TextChangeCommand))]
    private string _dataReceived;
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        serial = new SerialPort("COM2",115200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
    }
    
    [RelayCommand]
    public void TextChange()
    {
        serial.Open();
        serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

                if (sender is SerialPort port)
                {
                    while (port.BytesToRead > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] data = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
                        port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);                        
                        port.Write("ok"); //it work still fine here
                        DataReceived += data.ToString(); //it break the exception here, 
}
```

i debugged, and got exception at this line:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'

I also tried to start an invoke delegate, but it seems not work tho.  Any help explain and suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Code you posted is incomplete. `_dataReceived` is private string, what is `DataReceived` and where it is defined? The error you are getting indicates you are attempting to access UI elements from non-UI thread which requires Invoke.

Comment: @IgorLevicki `DataReceived` is auto-generated by the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservablePropertyAttribute`

Comment: Can you add your attempt at marshalling that call?

Comment: Although this answer is on a WInforms thread, the principle of marshaling the serial port data onto the UI thread is the same. It may be helpful to view: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556991/how-to-get-data-from-a-static-event-handler-for-serial-port/77557968#77557968](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77556991/how-to-get-data-from-a-static-event-handler-for-serial-port/77557968#77557968).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works just fine.

No, it does not. From the documentation of [SerialPort.DataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

> The DataReceived event is raised on a secondary thread when data is received from the SerialPort object. Because this event is raised on a secondary thread, and not the main thread, attempting to modify some elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a threading exception. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke, which will do the work on the proper thread.

The `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'` error is due to exactly this problem. In WPF this in effect means you cannot raise `PropertyChanged` from any background thread. Note that this error is not a guarantee, but updating the UI from a non-UI thread is wrong regardless if you get an error or not.

In many cases you can solve this problem by moving the execution to the UI thread. There are many ways to do this, but a typical approach would be to use the global dispatcher: `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=> DataReceived += data.ToString());`. Assuming the property raises `PropertyChanged` from it setter.

Also note that  you need to ensure your code is thread safe whenever you are using multiple threads. You can use the debuggers thread-window to check if you are running on the main thread or not when stopped at a breakpoint.

Also note that some UI frameworks automatically moves execution to the UI thread if needed. I would recommend not relying on this behavior, since it can easily result in problems if you are ever coding without such a framework.

Comment: Clearly. Yes, i though about raising it back to global thread tho but not know how. So the "just fine" in my old app will break cause the serial port failed after a lifetime, right?

Comment: @zyp8x It may depend on if you are running debug/release, or what kind of UI you are updating. Chances are it will stop working at some point.