# cant find a solution for "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'data' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arduino

i am new to the C# and .NET I am trying to make an app that receives data from arduino in string then cuts the long string to parts to read data for different variables(or sensors in my case). i trying to use dataReceived function from serial port and readline from serial and trying to show it on screen but it keeps giving me the same error

here is the main code block that couses the error

```
        public void dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.Text = Device.ReadLine();
            string littleData;
            string bigData = Device.ReadLine();
            littleData = bigData.Split('/')[0];
            dataA.Text = littleData;
            Task.Delay(1000);
        }
```

`Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'data' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on`

here is the rest of the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace stringToVaribleData_TEST_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PortsCB.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames());
            data.Text = "";
        }
        public void WriteToConsole(string messege, string TextColor)
        {
            ConsoleLogs.SelectionColor = Color.FromName(TextColor);
            ConsoleLogs.SelectedText += "/// " + messege + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConsoleLogs.Clear();
        }

        public void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string SelectedBaudRate = BaudRateCB.Text;
            string SelectedPort = PortsCB.Text;
            if (Device.IsOpen == false)
            {
                ///Try to open the port if cant give an error
                try
                {
                    ///Get user info
                    Device.BaudRate = int.Parse(SelectedBaudRate);
                    Device.PortName = SelectedPort;
                    Device.Open();
                    ///Check if the port open, if it is disable user input bloccks
                    if (Device.IsOpen == true)
                    {
                        ConnectButton.Text = "Disconnect";
                        BaudRateCB.Enabled = false;
                        PortsCB.Enabled = false;

                        WriteToConsole("Connected", "green");
                        Device.Write("get/device/info");
                    }
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException) { WriteToConsole("Something went wrong", "red"); }
                ///if post is used by other program output a error
                catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    WriteToConsole("port busy", "red");
                    Device.Close();
                }
                ///if port is allready open output an error
                catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    WriteToConsole("Port is already open", "red");
                    Device.Close();
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
                catch (System.ArgumentException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    if (PortsCB.Text == "" && BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port and baudrate", "red"); }
                    else if (PortsCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a port", "red"); }
                    else if (BaudRateCB.Text == "") { WriteToConsole("Please select a baudrate", "red"); }
                }
            }
            else if (Device.IsOpen == true)
            {
                WriteToConsole("Disconnected!!", "green");
                Device.Close();
                ConnectButton.Text = "Connect";
                BaudRateCB.Enabled = true; ;
                PortsCB.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public void Scan_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a list of serial port names.
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

            PortsCB.Items.Clear();
            PortsCB.Items.AddRange(ports);
            WriteToConsole("Found PORTS = ", "Green");
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                WriteToConsole(port, "Green");
            }
        }

        public void dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            data.Text = Device.ReadLine();
            string littleData;
            string bigData = Device.ReadLine();
            littleData = bigData.Split('/')[0];
            dataA.Text = littleData;
            Task.Delay(1000);
        }

    }
}
```

as i said before i don't have much experience with C# and .NET i tried researching but i couldn't find a solution that helped me

i also read that using background worker can fix this but i didn't get what it meant nor do i know how to use it

if someone can explain that i would be so happy

[also its my first Stack Overflow question so i apologize for any mistake or misuse]

Comment: You can only access a form (or any of its controls or properties) from the thread that created it. The `.Invoke` call on a form or control can _marshal_ a call to the Form's thread. If you search for _"Cross-thread operation not valid"_, you can find a ton of info about this, both on Stackoverflow and on Microsoft.com

Comment: You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77557968/5438626) helpful. It explains how to poll the com port and display the results in a Winforms control without cross-threading.

Comment: Side note: `Task.Delay` doesn't do anything unless you `await` it. And it makes no sense to use it in a `DataReceived` event.